# My simple jquery doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whats wrong? The console says undefined is not a function.

```
    var Input = $('#Formular :input');
for(i =0; i<Input.length; i++){
    Input[i].val(Daten[x-1][i]);
}
```

Comment: What line does it indicate as the source of the error? Maybe you forgot to include jQuery, and $ is undefined.

Comment: Probably because `var Input = $('#Formular :input');` In this $ is not defined

Comment: `Input[i]` is a `DOM` object that has no `val` So, you may have to do `Input[i].value="something"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is a jQuery function, but you use it on a DOM element.

You see, when doing `Input[i]`, you get the HTML element, not a jQuery object containing the element.

You either use the vanilla JS way to change value :

```
Input[i].value = Daten[x-1][i];
```

Or use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the element in a jQuery object :

```
Input.eq(i).val(Daten[x-1][i]);
```

You could also use the `.each` of jQuery :

```
var Input = $('#Formular :input').each(function(i){
    this.value = Daten[x-1][i];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Input already assign into Input variable, and in for loop you can't access the .val() function using those variable. Instead you need to assign the value using :

```
Input[i].value =Daten[x-1][i];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, extending what I have said in my comments, you could do the following.

```
//jQuery
var Inputs = $('#Formular :input');
Inputs.each(function(i){
    $(this).val("someval-" + i);
    //$(this).val(Daten[x-1][i]);
});

//Javascript (+ a bit of jQuery, the way you did)
var Inputs = $('#Formular :input');
for(i =0; i<Inputs.length; i++){
    Inputs[i].value = "some--val-" + i;
}
```

[Take a look at the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/4h6dee0r/1/)